# Update a Label only after UIButton animation is complete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I've used the code in an IBAction (button press) method:

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotateButton;  //don't forget to release
rotateButton = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotateButton.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
rotateButton.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((720*M_PI)/180)];
rotateButton.duration = 0.75;
rotateButton.repeatCount = 1;
[sender addAnimation:rotateButton forKey:@"720"];
```

and have a label that I want updated only after this is complete. I am wondering if there is a simple example anyone can provide me with to have the label only update when this is completed and not when the method is complete. I know you cannot use "@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)" because apple doesn't like it.   Help from anyone? Please and Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a UIView animation block?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    theButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((720*M_PI)/180);
} completion:^{
    theLabel.text = @"Whatever";
}];
```

If you need pre-4.x compatibility, use the old form, with the UIView class method `+setAnimationDidStopSelector:`, like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(someMethodInWhichYouSetTheLabelText)];
    theButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((720*M_PI)/180);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I went and tried the bottom code as I do want it to be pre-4x. Unfortunately I'm new to this and I'm getting an error:  "Request for member 'transform' in something not a struture or union" on the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation line.... any idea for an idiot like me?

Comment: btw.. the only way I could get the @selector to work on multiple pushes and to properly work with the setAnimationDidStop@selector was to use the line [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self] instead of [UIView commitAnimations]

Answer (score 0):

> I know you cannot use
>   "@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)"

Actually you can, just give it another name so it will not clash with Apple internal method

About your problem:

[CAAnimation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation)

> *delegate*
>
> Specifies the receiver’s
>   delegate object.
>
> *animationDidStop:finished:*
>
> Called when
>   the animation completes its active
>   duration or is removed from the object
>   it is attached to.